# How to show a QToolTip on mouse press event and leave it popped up for some time? Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Trying to show a tool tip on mouse press event and make it popped up for some time. For now it shows only if a mouse button is pressed.

[image]

```
void ::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
{
    if (!m_isLinkingAvailable)
    {
        QToolTip::showText(e->screenPos().toPoint(),
            tr("Symbol Linking\navailable only for Price"), this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Ian Burns's answer I have manged to create own approach:

```
void ::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)
{
    QTimer::singleShot(200, [this]()
        {
            QToolTip::showText(mapToGlobal({}),
                tr("Symbol Linking\navailable only for Price"), this);
        });
}
```

Somehow if I show a tooltip inside mousePressEvent method it disappears immediately after I unpress the mouse button. QTimer delays the pop up call and it stays popped for reasonable time.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Qt Docs, looks like there's an [alternate method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtooltip.html#showText-2) for this function:

> void QToolTip::showText(const QPoint &pos, const QString &text, QWidget *w, const QRect &rect, **int msecDisplayTime**)

You should be able to specify a time for how long to display the tooltip.

**EDIT:**

Okay so seems like this method doesn't work as expected with a mousePress event, so here's an alternative using a QTimer:

Add these to your class:

```cpp
MyConstructor(...params...)
        , m_tooltipTimer(new QTimer(this)) // don't forget this line
    {
        connect(m_tooltipTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateTooltip()));
        setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::AllButtons);
    }

...

public slots:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    void updateTooltip();

...

private:
    QPoint m_tooltipPos;
    qint64 m_tooltipTimerStart;
    QTimer *m_tooltipTimer;
```

And then implement these in your .cpp

```cpp
void ::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    m_tooltipTimer->start(200); // 5x per second, automatically resets timer if already started
    m_tooltipTimerStart = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
    m_tooltipPos = event->globalPos();
    event->accept();
}

void ::updateTooltip() {
    auto howLongShown = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - m_tooltipTimerStart; // startTime here is the moment of first showing of the tooltip
    qDebug() << howLongShown;
    if (howLongShown < 1000) { // 1 sec
        QToolTip::showText(m_tooltipPos, tr("Test Tooltip")); // Replace this with your own
    } else {
        QToolTip::hideText();
        m_tooltipTimer->stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still the same behavior. It is popped up til I keep a mouse button pressed. I guess it is up to events.

Comment: @Mikhail Yeah, I just tried it out locally and figured out a solution using a QTimer. I edited my answer with an updated solution.